# Emailing service health results to inbox

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I'm writing a powershell script that will take two arrays, one composed of servers and the other of specific services running on them, and ensure they are running. If not, the service will be restarted, then the others will continue to be checked. What I also want is to add some logging of these results, that can be emailed for me to check periodically to make sure things are running fine. The CheckServices function appears to be working as intended, but when the email is sent there is nothing in the email.

$results = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@()

```
$computers = @(
   
)

$checklist = @(
   
)

Function CheckServices {

    foreach ($servers in $computers) {
        foreach ($service in $checklist) {
            $state = (Invoke-Command -ComputerName $servers {param ($service) Get-Service -Name $service}-ArgumentList $service -Credential $cred).status

            switch ($state) {
            'Running' {$results.Add("$service on $servers running normally")}
            'Stopped' {$results.Add("$service on $servers has stopped"); Invoke-Command -ComputerName $servers {param ($service) Restart-Service -Name $service}-ArgumentList $service -Credential $cred}
            $null {continue}
            
                }
            
            } 
        }   

    New-Email -EmailBody $results -Subject "Service Status Report" -Message "Please find attached a report of service status. If this email is empty, there were no services that stopped overnight"
    
}
```

```
Function New-Email {
    Param(
        [Parameter(mandatory=$false)]
        [string]
        $Attachment
        ,
        [Parameter(mandatory=$false)]
        [PSCustomObject[]]
        $EmailBody
        ,
        [Parameter(mandatory=$true)]
        [string]
        $Message
        ,
        [Parameter(mandatory=$true)]
        [string]
        $Subject
    )
    try {
        Write-Logfile -ActionType INFO -Message "Function New-Email: Attempting to email results..." 
        $style = "<style>BODY{font-family: Arial; font-size: 10pt;}"
        $style = $style + "TABLE{border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse;}"
        $style = $style + "TH{border: 1px solid black; background: #dddddd; padding: 5px;text-align: center; }"
        $style = $style + "TD{border: 1px solid black; padding: 5px;text-align: center; }"
        $style = $style + "</style>"

        $BodyResults = $EmailBody | ConvertTo-Html -Fragment | Out-String
        $bodyMessage = $Message 
        $Body = ConvertTo-Html -Head "$($bodyMessage) `n$($Style)" -PostContent $BodyResults | Out-String
        If (!$Attachment) {
            Send-MailMessage -bodyashtml -From $EmailFrom -to $EmailTo -subject $Subject -body $body -SmtpServer $PSEmailServer
            Write-Logfile -ActionType SUCCESS -Message "Function New-Email:  Results emailed with no attachment!"
        } Else {
            Send-MailMessage -bodyashtml -Attachments $Attachment -From $EmailFrom -to $EmailTo -subject $Subject -body $body -SmtpServer $PSEmailServer
            Write-Logfile -ActionType SUCCESS -Message "Function New-Email:  Results emailed with attachment [$($Attachment)]!"
        }
    }
    catch {

        Write-Logfile -ActionType ERROR -Message "Function New-Email: Unable to email results!" 
        Write-Logfile -ActionType ERROR -Message $Error
    }

}
```

```
Function Write-Logfile {
    Param(
    [Parameter(mandatory=$true)]
    [string]
    $ActionType,
    [Parameter(mandatory=$true)]
    [string]
    $Message
    )

    $LogFile = "$currentloc\CoreServiceHealthExperiment.txt"

    $Date = Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd"
    $Time = Get-Date -Format "HH:mm"

    Write-Output "$($Date) $($Time)    [$ActionType]    $Message" | Out-File $LogFile -Append
    Write-Host "$($Date) $($Time)    [$ActionType]    $Message"

}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, Eddie. From which module is `New-Email`? Is there any error message?

Comment: Apologies, its a function I made that works with the exchange powershell module. I've added it along with the logging one I made as well.